# How to preg_match a variable which can be NULL in PHP?

Tags: php, string, null, preg-match

I got a problem with the PHP function preg_match today.

I want to match exact 12 characters in a string (`$test='123456789012'`) OR `$test = NULL`

My problem is the OR NULL call how is the RegEx for this NULL variable.

Tried: `preg_match("/^([\w.-]{12})|(NULL)$/",$test);`

Comment: Can't you use isset() to detect null, and if not null, use preg_match() ?

Comment: `NULL` is not a string *NULL*

Comment: problem of isset() is that it could be around 20 parameters to check it would be nice if everything could be checked directly in the preg_match() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NULL` value is not a string literal with the letters **NULL**, so if you're searching for **NULL** when something is `NULL` they will never match.

You can do

```
if($test)
    preg_match("/^([\w.-]{12})$/",$test);
else
    //whatever works
```

Comment: good idea but is it possible to do every check direct in the RegEx? because I want it to be as small as possible without 20 if/else blocks. An option could be building a new function to do everything but i would like to know if there is any way to check for NULL direct in the RegEx.

Comment: A `NULL` value as a string literal in a REGEX would be a blank value you could check for that

Comment: my approach at the moment is the following:
`if((preg_match("/^[\w.-]{12}$/", $teststring) || !isset($teststring)) > 0) {`

Comment: There is no need for isset result to be compared with 0, it returns TRUE or FALSE so just `isset($teststring)` is fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tested the code and it works with the isset() outside of the >0 . I'll accept your answer even if it isn't the way I do it. It still works this way.

Comment: Your code works the same way, this one just has one added benefit that if the string is NULL it doesn't waste time calling `preg_match` on it. Other than that your code and this code mean the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Slightly late, but you can try '^$' to match NULL:

```
preg_match('/^[\w.-]{12}$|^$/',$test);
```